# Vercel Deployment with BE & Database Still in Heroku

Tags: heroku, deployment, vercel

My organization is currently trying to move away from Heroku and we just migrated our React.js app to Nextjs. Originally I had considered going with AWS but Vercel seems to have a lot of benefits that would help us in the long term.

Currently our Laravel backend is still hosted in Heroku with a Postgres database. When I try to deploy, it appears that I cannot make a GET call.

This Next.js code works as expected on a Heroku dyno, but not when I attempt to deploy to Vercel.

Are there any gotchas, or considerations I should be aware of? Has anyone else ran into this issue? [image: related errors]

[image: more related errors]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figured out what it was. Hope this helps somebody else! We had the .next build in our .gitignore folder because we had to switch back and forth between a legacy project and the .next folder caused some big issues. We just removed it and everything is building as expected. Still curious as to why it worked in Heroku and not Vercel though.